# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './user/user.module'

Tags: angular, angular-module

I am trying lazy loading of the module and getting below error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './user/user.module'
```

**UserModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { userRoutes } from './user.routes';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(userRoutes)],
  declarations: [ProfileComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Added path to my path in userRoutes 
`{ path: 'user', loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule' }`

**Full Error Stack**

```
core.js:6241 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './user/user.module'
Error: Cannot find module './user/user.module'
    at $_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:5
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:41667)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:363)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:123)
    at zone-evergreen.js:857
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41645)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41645)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:484)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1621)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new way to load modules is by using arrow functions

Add the below path to app routing ts

```
{ path: 'user', loadChildren: ()=> import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)}:
```

And then in your lazy loaded module user routing one add like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UsersComponent
  }
];
```

If your creating the angular app in the latest version then use the above way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use UserModule inside UserModule only?
You mentioned you are defining the lazyloading part in userRoutes. That is incorrect.
Please define in app-routing.module.ts
And the path should be relative to app-routing.module.ts